# git with --git-dir= results in 'not a git repository'

Tags: git, bash, terminal, sh

I have a script in one of my iOS apps that should get the git revision hash and put it in the version number. In this script I run git --git-dir="$PROJECT_DIR" show -s --pretty=format:%h for that. However, I get the message that the directory isn't a git repository. If I echo the PROJECT_DIR var and go to the terminal the following works:

```
cd projectDirPath
git show -s --pretty=format:%h
```

What doesn't work is:

```
git --git-dir=projectDirPath show -s --pretty=format:%h
```

Am I missing something? The documentation states, that I can specify the path to a git repository with --git-dir and the specified path obviously is a git repository as all the git commands work without any problem if I first cd into that path. However if I am not in this path, specifing --git-dir doesn't work.

Comment: `--git-dir` needs to point at the `.git` folder of your repository.  Try `git --git-dir=projectDirPath/.git show -s --pretty=format:%h`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. You might want to post this as an answer so I can flag it as the answer to the problem!

Comment: Great!  I posted this as an answer as well.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

When using [`--git-dir`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---git-dirltpathgt), you need to point at the `.git` folder of your repository.  Try:

```
git --git-dir=projectDirPath/.git show -s --pretty=format:%h
```

The doc on `--git-dir` says that:

> --git-dir=
>
> Set the path to the repository (".git" directory). This can also be controlled by setting the GIT_DIR environment variable. It can be an absolute path or relative path to current working directory.

I use to have an issue remembering this myself. To help me remember what to do, I try to remember that the option is asking for exactly what it wants: the path to the `.git` directory (git-dir).

Comment: Just a clarification: **projectDirPath** should be an absolute (NOT a relative) path.

Comment: @BryanJyhHerngChong Actually, that is incorrect.  The git manpage says "It can be an absolute path or relative path to current working directory."

Comment: @BryanJyhHerngChong This is not true. I have added the relevant doc in the answer. The path can be a relative path.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the [git -C command line option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--Cltpathgt).

> `-C <path>`
>
> Run as if git was started in `<path>` instead of the current
> working directory. When multiple `-C` options are given, each
> subsequent non-absolute `-C <path>` is interpreted relative to the
> preceding `-C <path>`. If `<path>` is present but empty, e.g.  `-C ""`,
> then the current working directory is left unchanged.
>
> This option affects options that expect path name like `--git-dir`
> and `--work-tree` in that their interpretations of the path names
> would be made relative to the working directory caused by the `-C`
> option. For example the following invocations are equivalent:
>
> ```
> git --git-dir=a.git --work-tree=b -C c status
> git --git-dir=c/a.git --work-tree=c/b status
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Apart of `--git-dir`, also setting `--work-tree` may help. For the script, it's good to use relevant environments (it's easier), e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/repo
export GIT_DIR=/path/to/repo/.git
git show -s --pretty=format:%h
```