# Change top level .git directory that it points to?

Tags: git

I originally did a

```
git init
```

while I was on a pc that was mapped to a network drive. The computer that was doing the actual file work was on a remote server (I was accessing a mapped network drive in the terminal when I did `git init`)

If I am accessing the files and using git commands like `git status` from the mapped drive all is good

Its when I remote into the actual server that has the files on its hard drive and try to do

```
git status
```

it says the following:

fatal: Could not switch to 'Y:/': No such file or directory

On the computer I was using to do the `git init` the mapped drive was named `Y:` (the server was mapped to the `Y:` drive)

On the actual server, however, the files are actually sitting in the `D:` drive

Is there something I can do WITHOUT changing the mapped drive and actual drive to be the same drive name so this can be fixed where I can use git while working remotely and while actually logging in

If there is nothing I can do without changing the directory names so be it I guess..

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following question helped me answer it and figure it out myself

[What is GIT_WORK_TREE, why have I never needed to set this ENV var, why now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283262/what-is-git-work-tree-why-have-i-never-needed-to-set-this-env-var-why-now)

and this one

[git with --git-dir= results in 'not a git repository'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872446/git-with-git-dir-results-in-not-a-git-repository)

I had to do the following command when I ran `git status`

```
git --git-dir=/d/.git --work-tree=/d/ status
```

where `/d/` is synonymous with D:/